# Getting info periodically from server, and looking for change to stdin to compare the two

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have written a program that gets data from a server and shows it on the screen.  I update the display periodically (1s), I may change that to update on a change in the data.
I want to be able to scan a barcode and compare the data contained in it to the data I read from the server. I can scan the barcode with input(), but obviously can't use that asynchronously.
I'm stuck trying to figure out how to look for change in the barcode info and acting on it if it has changed, or continue on if it has not changed. Something like a non-blocking input().
Something along the lines of the "code" below.  No idea how to get this working.

```
import asyncio

async def get_network_data():
    # get data from network - do I need an await here?
    return net_data

async def get_barcode_data():
    await whatever_this_needs_to_be_to_read_barcode()
    return (yield?) barcode_data

def compare_the_two(net_data, barcode_data):
    if barcode_data != old_barcode:
        old_barcode = barcode_data
        if net_data != barcode_data:
            print(f'Wrong scan!  Net Data {net_data} does not match barcode {barcode_data}')
            # Or whatever I decide to do with a mismatch
        else:
            # continue on
    else:
        # keep on reading data from network and waiting for barcode scan
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with using asyncio so I could be wrong but it sounds like you would want to use the threading module instead. This means you can have a worker thread for your blocking input and the main thread can deal with whatever input data you currently have. You could also run the networking in another thread to make sure you don't have to wait for it.

Comment: Realized I'm an idiot.  I don't need asyncio, I'm already using tkinter for the GUI.

Comment: I can just have an Entry box to accept the scan.  Then I realized I could just bind the <Key> event and build the code from that and not have to worry about an Entry box.

Comment: That's good. Comment if you need something otherwise you can just mark the question as answered.